# Сравнение двух таблиц для авторизации, Сервер MSSQL

Tags: sql-server

Сервер MSSQL. Есть две таблицы, 1й таблице находятся логины и пароли всех сотрудников, в ней есть также KodSotr, во 2й таблице находятся только секретари, кроме того вместо KodSotr стоит в ней Kod и коды соответствуют друг другу. Кроме того в php переменные сравнивают логи и пароль к первой таблице **Вопрос:** Какой запрос может авторизововать только Секретарей? 
вот мой запрос:

```
    $sql = ("SELECT KodSotr, Login, Passw 
FROM [usersINEU].[dbo].[tbUsersPGPI] LEFT JOIN 
[College].[dbo].[tb_Secret] ON 
[usersINEU].[dbo].[tbUsersPGPI].[KodSotr] = [College].[dbo].[tb_Secret].[Kod] 
 WHERE (Login = '".$username."') AND (Passw =  '".$password."')");
```

Comment: Учебные задания нужно делать самому.

Comment: Читать [Join Fundamentals](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms191517%28v%3dsql.105%29) и [Using Joins](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms191472%28v%3dsql.105%29) до полного усвоения.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = ("SELECT * FROM [usersINEU].[dbo].[tbUsersPGPI] WHERE (Login = '" .$username. "') AND (Passw = '" .$password. "') AND [KodSotr] IN (SELECT [Kod] FROM [College].[dbo].[tb_Secret])");
```

Я решил эту проблему так

Comment: спасибо за SQL Injection